# Are the sum of the upper half of the dividers greater than or equal to the double of the lower half?

Tags: inequality

If $N=12$ then the dividers are $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $6$, $12$ then 
$2*(1+2+3)<(4+6+12)$, can i prove that this happens for any $N$? 
N is not a perfect square

Comment: it is for non perfect square numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality does not hold for $N=2$.
So let $N>2$ be a non-square.
Let $p$ be any prime divisor of $N$ and let $N$ have the $d=2k$ divisors $1=a_1<a_2<\ldots <a_d=N$.
Let $$A=\{\,x\in\Bbb N: x\mid N\,\}$$ be the set of divisors of $N$, let $$B:=\{\,x\in A:p\nmid x\,\},\quad C:=\{\,x\in A:p\mid x\,\}$$
be the divisors not divisible by $p$ and divisible by $p$, respectively.
Note that $B\to C$, $x\mapsto px$ is injective, hence $|B|\le k\le |C|$.
Let $c_1< \ldots< c_k$ be  $k$ distinct elements of $C$. Then the $c_i$ are *some* distinct divisors of $N$ and the $\frac{c_i}p$ are *some* distinct divisors of $N$.
Hence$$\begin{align} p(a_1+\ldots+a_k)&\le p\left(\frac{c_1}p+\cdots +\frac{c_k}p\right)\\&=c_1+\cdots +c_k\\&\le a_{k+1}+\ldots +a_{2k}.\end{align}$$
If $p>2$, we are done. remains the case when our only choice is $p=2$, i.e., when $N$ is a power of $2$. Then necessarily $N=2^{2k-1}$ with $k\ge 2$, $a_{k+i}=2^{k}a_i$, and  so
$$ 2^k(a_1+\ldots+a_k)= a_{k+1}+\ldots +a_{2k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The first half of the divisors of $N$ are all $\le \lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$ so the double of their sum is upper bounded by:

$$\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor(\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor+1)\le N+\sqrt{N}$$

So:

- If $N$ is prime, it easily satisfies the property.
- If $N$ is composite, there are at least two terms in the upper part: $N$ and one factor of $N$ which is greater than $\sqrt{N}$. Then we can just use the previous inequality.